# How to send to a list of numbers in a text file using twilio python script?

Tags: python, twilio, sms

this code below sends an sms text to one number :

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
message = client.messages \
 .create(
                 body="Message Here",
                 from_='Sender Name',
                 to='+123456789'
             )
```

But I don't want to send number by number, how can i send to a list of numbers which are in a text file called num.txt as an example ?

Comment: Why did you not do it as you described?

Comment: @mkrieger1 im looking for a solution , i dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a file with Python's `open` function and then iterate over the lines in the file with a for loop. So, if your numbers are all on different lines in your file, then you can accomplish this like so:

```py
import os
from twilio.rest import Client
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

with open("num.txt") as file:
  for number in file:
    message = client.messages \
      .create(
        body="Message Here",
        from_='Sender Name',
        to=number
      )
```